IMU Data Integration for EuRoC Dataset in Python
I'm trying to derive the pose of a drone (x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw) using IMU data in the form:
(timestamp, Angular Velocity X, Angular Velocity Y, Angular Velocity Z, Acceleration X, Acceleration Y, Acceleration Z)
Where angular velocity is in rad/s, velocity is in m/s^2, and timestamps are in ns.
My approach uses scipy's cumtrapz to take the antiderivative over each field in the dataset independently:
# T, GX, GY, GZ, AX, AY, AZ = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

        dt = (nparr[:,T])/(10**(9)) # Convert to seconds
        dt = dt - dt[0] # Adjust s.t. all timestamps start with 0

        for field in [AX, AY, AZ]:
            first_antiderivative = integrate.cumtrapz(nparr[:,field], x=dt)
            second_antiderivative = integrate.cumtrapz(first_antiderivative, x=dt[:-1]) 
            integrated[:,field] = second_antiderivative

        for field in [GX, GY, GZ]:
            first_antiderivative = integrate.cumtrapz(nparr[:,field], x=dt)
            integrated[:,field] = first_antiderivative[:-1]

This is giving me the following graph, where integrated VO (red) is very wrong compared to ground truth (green):

Any idea what I'm missing? Alternatively, does anyone know of any packages that would be able to integrate IMU data in this format? Original dataset is EuRoC
Just to be clear, I'm looking to get solely the drifted UWB IMU pose, not correct for error with this step.
Thanks,
